# Tail recursive function to find depth of a tree in Ocaml

Tags: tree, functional-programming, ocaml, binary-tree

I have a type `tree` defined as follows

```
type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree ;;
```

I have a function to find the depth of the tree as follows

```
let rec depth = function 
    | Leaf x -> 0
    | Node(_,left,right) -> 1 + (max (depth left) (depth right))
;;
```

This function is not tail recursive. Is there a way for me to write this function in tail recursive way?

Comment: I believe you can if you transform to continuation passing style.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can trivially do this by turning the function into CPS (Continuation Passing Style). The idea is that instead of calling `depth left`, and then computing things based on this result, you call `depth left (fun dleft -> ...)`, where the second argument is "what to compute once the result (`dleft`) is available".

```
let depth tree =
  let rec depth tree k = match tree with
    | Leaf x -> k 0
    | Node(_,left,right) ->
      depth left (fun dleft ->
        depth right (fun dright ->
          k (1 + (max dleft dright))))
  in depth tree (fun d -> d)
```

This is a well-known trick that can make any function tail-recursive. Voilà, it's tail-rec.

The next well-known trick in the bag is to "defunctionalize" the CPS result. The representation of continuations (the `(fun dleft -> ...)` parts) as functions is neat, but you may want to see what it looks like as data. So we replace each of these closures by a concrete constructor of a datatype, that captures the free variables used in it.

Here we have three continuation closures: `(fun dleft -> depth right (fun dright -> k ...))`, which only reuses the environment variables `right` and `k`, `(fun dright -> ...)`, which reuses `k` and the now-available left result `dleft`, and `(fun d -> d)`, the initial computation, that doesn't capture anything.

```
type ('a, 'b) cont =
  | Kleft of 'a tree * ('a, 'b) cont (* right and k *)
  | Kright of 'b * ('a, 'b) cont     (* dleft and k *)
  | Kid
```

The defunctorized function looks like this:

```
let depth tree =
  let rec depth tree k = match tree with
    | Leaf x -> eval k 0
    | Node(_,left,right) ->
      depth left (Kleft(right, k))
  and eval k d = match k with
    | Kleft(right, k) ->
      depth right (Kright(d, k))
    | Kright(dleft, k) ->
      eval k (1 + max d dleft)
    | Kid -> d
  in depth tree Kid
;;
```

Instead of building a function `k` and applying it on the leaves (`k 0`), I build a data of type `('a, int) cont`, which needs to be later `eval`uated to compute a result. `eval`, when it gets passed a `Kleft`, does what the closure `(fun dleft -> ...)` was doing, that is it recursively call `depth` on the right subtree. `eval` and `depth` are mutually recursive.

Now look hard at `('a, 'b) cont`, what is this datatype? It's a list!

```
type ('a, 'b) next_item =
  | Kleft of 'a tree
  | Kright of 'b

type ('a, 'b) cont = ('a, 'b) next_item list

let depth tree =
  let rec depth tree k = match tree with
    | Leaf x -> eval k 0
    | Node(_,left,right) ->
      depth left (Kleft(right) :: k)
  and eval k d = match k with
    | Kleft(right) :: k ->
      depth right (Kright(d) :: k)
    | Kright(dleft) :: k ->
      eval k (1 + max d dleft)
    | [] -> d
  in depth tree []
;;
```

And a list is a stack. What we have here is actually a reification (transformation into data) of the call stack of the previous recursive function, with two different cases corresponding to the two different kinds of non-tailrec calls.

Note that the defunctionalization is only there for fun. In pratice the CPS version is short, easy to derive by hand, rather easy to read, and I would recommend using it. Closures must be allocated in memory, but so are elements of `('a, 'b) cont` -- albeit those might be represented more compactly`. I would stick to the CPS version unless there are very good reasons to do something more complicated.

Comment: I think Thomas's answer is a little better, as it is clearer and more efficient.

Comment: It all depends on whether the OP is trying to learn how to make *a* function tail-recursive, or *this* function.

Comment: The good thing about Reynolds defunctionalization of CPS-converted code is that it recovers, more or less mechanically, the well-known tail-recursive accumulating versions of regular (i.e., with only one kind of recursive call) non-tail-recursive functions, in that the type of reified continuations is invariably isomorphic to the type of lists.

Comment: One of the reasons for making something tail recursive is to save space.  It's not the only reason, but it is often the driving force.  It strikes me that making this particular problem tail recursive via CPS doesn't save space.  It seems to turn stack frames into functions in a 1:1 ratio.  Can someone correct me here if I'm incorrect on this?

Comment: @Steve, it is correct that this transformation has the same complexity than the original non-tailrec version -- indeed, it would be just a bit too good to have a general technique to reduce space usage of any recursive function! Yet I'd say that the general motivation for tailrec is rather to save *stack* space, for implementations that use the C/OS/hardware stack, because it is much more severely restricted than the rest of memory. In the happy cases where you can reduce space complexity, you're actually writing a new, different algorithm.

Comment: That said, the defunctionalized CPS version sometimes help in finding this new space-efficient algorithm: you can sometimes derive this better version by equational reasoning on the CPS-defunctionalized code. If you try for example this technique on the `length : 'a list -> int` function, you'll notice that the resulting `cont` type is isomorphic to integers, and using integers instead directly gives you the constant-memory tailrec version.

Answer (score 17):

In this case (depth computation), you can accumulate over pairs (`subtree depth` * `subtree content`) to obtain the following tail-recursive function:

```
let depth tree =
  let rec aux depth = function
    | [] -> depth
    | (d, Leaf _) :: t -> aux (max d depth) t
    | (d, Node (_,left,right)) :: t ->
      let accu = (d+1, left) :: (d+1, right) :: t in
      aux depth accu in
aux 0 [(0, tree)]
```

For more general cases, you will indeed need to use the CPS transformation described by Gabriel.

Comment: Indeed this is a much neater presentation for this particular algorithm. You can actually understand this algorithm as a composition of two techniques: the use of lists is a usual tailrec-ification of a depth-first traversal (one use a FIFO queue of next neighbors for breadth-first traversal, and a LIFO list for depth-first), and the threaded parameter `depth` is a hidden state monad that is used to accumulate information about the result -- a reference would also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's a neat and generic solution using `fold_tree` and CPS - continuous passing style:

```
let fold_tree tree f acc =
  let loop t cont =
    match tree with
    | Leaf -> cont acc
    | Node (x, left, right) ->
      loop left (fun lacc ->
        loop right (fun racc ->
          cont @@ f x lacc racc))
  in loop tree (fun x -> x)

let depth tree = fold_tree tree (fun x dl dr -> 1 + (max dl dr)) 0
```