# finding the number of occurrences of a variable in a binary tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

i want to find the number of occurrences of some number in any tree.And here is my code but it gives an error which i can not find why it happens.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (a ,Tree a,Tree a) deriving (Show)

occurst _ Empty = 0     -- this line occurs error
occurst a ( Node (x,left,right) ) = if x==Empty then 0
            else if a==x then 1 + (occurst a left) + (occurst a right)
            else (occurst a left) + (occurst a right)  


j=let t = Node (3 , Node (2 , Node (1 , Empty , Empty ) , Node (1 , Empty , Empty )),Node     (1 , Node (2 , Node (1 , Empty , Empty ) , Node (1 , Empty , Empty )),Node    (1,Empty,Empty)))  
  in occurst 1 t
```

Error message is that:

```
ERROR "treeExample.hs":95 - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Eq (Tree a)
*** Expression : occurst
```

INput Outputs must be :

```
occurst 1 t -> 6
occurst 2 t -> 2
occurst 3 t ->1
occurst 4 t ->0
```

Comment: Why does the `Node` need a tuple?  What's wrong with `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tail recursive version:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

occurst x t = go 0 [t] where
  go n [] = n
  go n (t:ts) = case t of
                  Empty      -> go n ts
                  Node a l r -> let n' = n + fromEnum (a==x)
                                in n' `seq` go n' (l:r:ts)

j = occurst 1 t where
  t = (Node 3
        (Node 2
          (Node 1 Empty Empty)
          (Node 1 Empty Empty ))
        (Node 1
          (Node 2
            (Node 1 Empty Empty)
            (Node 1 Empty Empty))
          (Node 1 Empty Empty)))
```

Comment: You'll want to add some strictness to `n`, though, either with `seq` or a bang pattern. Otherwise you'll just build up a large thunk.

Comment: @hammar, doh!  Fixed (I think)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your function very concisely:

```
occurst _ Empty = 0   
occurst a ( Node (x,left,right) ) = 
   fromEnum (x==a) + (occurst a left) + (occurst a right)
```

`fromEnum` converts an `Enum` to an `Int`, and fortunately not only `Bool` is actually an `Enum`, but `False` maps to 0 and `True` to 1.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the line

```
occurst a ( Node (x,left,right) ) = if x==Empty then 0
```

you are saying that `x` is a `Tree` ... really don't know what this `if` is for

This one will work as expected:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (a ,Tree a,Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

occurst _ Empty = 0
occurst a ( Node (x,left,right) ) =
            if a==x then 1 + (occurst a left) + (occurst a right)
            else (occurst a left) + (occurst a right)
```

BTW: I did not change your naming nor your basic algorithm but please note that this one is not very stack-friendly as it's not tail-recursive.

Comment: They don't need to tell Haskell that Tree is an instance of Eq --- the whole trying-to-compare-a-Tree thing is a bug (in this function).

Comment: Dave is right sorry - that what you get if you just do what the compiler tells you ;)

Comment: How would you make this tail recursive?  Would you accumulate a list of sub-trees yet to be visited?  Is that more efficient than just letting the stack to it?

Comment: Continuations don't magically turn a linear space algorithm into a constant space one.

Comment: the question was for a tail-recursive algorithm ... but never mind, that was and is not the subject here (you can find a question on that subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323036/tail-recursive-function-to-find-depth-of-a-tree-in-ocaml)