# finding sum of tree to list using haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to apply sum using id function while giving input to program.but i am with below. any guidance is much appreciated.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
reduce_tree :: Tree a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b
reduce_tree (Leaf v) = [v]
reduce_tree (Node left root right) = reduce_tree left ++ [root] ++   reduce_tree right
```

input as follows:

```
ghci> reduce_tree (VNode (VLeaf 1) 2 (VNode (VLeaf 3) 4 (VLeaf 5)))
                   id sum
                   where sum t1 v t2 = t1 + v + t2
15
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, looks like it's working as intended...

Comment: @luqui: i want to do sum on tree to list with the below function type but i m not getting any idea ,                                                                                                  reduce_tree :: Tree a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b

Comment: @luqui : with the below function type i am trying to do sum of tree to list  reduce_tree :: Tree a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't understand your question completely, here are some observations:

- `reduce_tree`'s type signature suggests that it should have more arguments than you give it.

  If `f` is a function that maps values of type `a` to values of type `b`, and `g` is what appears to be an accumulating function of three arguments (although I'm unsure why two are not enough), then

  ```
  reduce_tree :: Tree a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b
  reduce_tree (Leaf v) f g = ...
  reduce_tree (Node left v right) f g = ...
  ```
- If `reduce_tree` is in fact a reduce function, and not one that simply flattens trees into lists, you may draw inspiration from [`Data.Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html).

  ```
  data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)

  treefold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
  treefold f acc (Leaf x) = f x acc
  treefold f acc1 (Node left x right) =
    let acc2 = treefold f acc1 right
        acc3 = f x acc2
        acc4 = treefold f acc3 left
    in acc4
  ```

  With such a function you can either flatten or sum the elements of a tree:

  ```
  flattenTree :: Tree a -> [a]
  flattenTree tree = treefold (:) [] tree

  sumTree :: Num a => Tree a -> a
  sumTree tree = treefold (+) 0 tree
  ```
- The only bell that rings when you say "apply sum using id function" is that perhaps you wish to use continuations. This is already covered thoroughly in e.g. [Haskell: tail recursion version of depth of binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205213/haskell-tail-recursion-version-of-depth-of-binary-tree) and concisely in [Tail-recursion on trees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19070577/235908) (Standard ML). A Haskell equivalent would be:

  ```
  treefold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
  treefold f acc tree = tf f acc tree id
    where
      tf f acc (Leaf x) k = k (f x acc)
      tf f acc (Node left x right) old_k = tf f left acc new_k
        where
          new_k = \acc -> tf f right (f x acc) old_k
  ```

  Now `sumTree` can be defined in the exact same way as before, except it would use folding as well as the identity function as the initial continuation. Or you could extract the helper function `tf` to the top-level if you want to feed the traversal function with the function `id` yourself.

Comment: below is how you told me to find sum of tree code:                                                                                                       data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)
    treefold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
    treefold f acc (Leaf x) = f x acc
    treefold f acc1 (Node left x right) =
      let acc2 = treefold f acc1 right
      acc3 = f x acc2
      acc4 = treefold f acc3 left in acc4
       sumTree :: Num a => Tree a -> a
       sumTree tree = treefold (+) 0 tree

Comment: ghci> sumTree (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5)))
15

Comment: but how can i find sum at run time as below :                                     data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq) treefold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b                                      treefold f acc (Leaf x) = f x acc  treefold f acc1 (Node left x right) = let acc2 = treefold f acc1 right acc3 = f x acc2 acc4 = treefold f acc3 left in acc4  flattenTree :: Tree a -> [a]                                                    flattenTree tree = treefold (:) [] tree

Comment: ghci> flattenTree (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5)))id sum where sum t1 v t2 = t1 + v + t2     then ouput : 15

Answer (score 2):

Oh, if I understand correctly, I think you are just trying to enter your example into ghci.  I would recommend putting the complexity in the file:

```
sum_tree :: Tree Int -> Int
sum_tree t = reduce_tree t id sum
    where sum t1 v t2 = t1 + v + t2
```

then in ghci, after you have loaded the file that `sum_tree` and `reduce_tree` are defined in,

```
ghci> sum_tree (VNode (VLeaf 1) 2 (VNode (VLeaf 3) 4 (VLeaf 5))
```

If you must do it all in ghci, be aware that you can't use `where` in ghci usually, since `where` is only used in definitions.  Use `let ... in` instead:

```
ghci> let sum t1 v t2 = t1 + v + t2 in reduce_tree (VNode (VLeaf 1) 2 (VNode (VLeaf 3) 4 (VLeaf 5))) id sum
```

If you for some reason don't want to use let, you can use a lambda:

```
ghci> reduce_tree (VNode (VLeaf 1) 2 (VLeaf 3)) id (\t1 v t2 -> t1 + v + t2)
```

Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. actually i want to give identity function and sum function in ghci itself not using let... for ex:                                      ghci> reduce_tree (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 5))) id sum where sum t1 v t2 = t1+v+t2                                                                                              then the output is 15

Comment: Uh, ok... I edited my answer with another suggestion.  You can't use `where` in ghci.

Comment: :with the below function type i am trying to do sum of tree to list reduce_tree :: Tree a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b

Comment: Oh of course, `reduce_tree` is wrong, I didn't notice!  See other answer.

Comment: can u explain clearly with the function type i mentioned.. i got confused