# Binary Tree sum with Scala Delimited Continuations

Tags: scala, tree, tail-recursion, continuations, delimited-continuations

I am playing around with Scala and I am starting from some simple examples such as implementing binary trees. Having prior knowledge of functional programming (OCaml, F#) I was trying to replicate the common approach of using continuations in order to make a binary tree traversal tail-recursive.
I am reading as much as I can about Scala's Delimited Continuations, but I have not been able to make it work.

You can read an OCaml implementation of this behaviour from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323036/tail-recursive-function-to-find-depth-of-a-tree-in-ocaml)

I followed the examples in this *[Introduction to Programming with Shift and Reset](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihw4nUiYTNAhUENhoKHbMSARsQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.is.ocha.ac.jp%2F~asai%2Fcw2011tutorial%2Fmain-e.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHvcj9tbrBSppZMwp9QBdSzZ-0Y3g&sig2=hwVsLGLPgrmxnl3NRFWIvg)*, but I am always getting type errors and the modifications I made to try making it work, gave correct results, but without making the function tail recursive.

Here's my implementation

```
abstract class IntTree
case object EmptyTree extends IntTree
case class Node( value : Int, left : IntTree, right : IntTree) extends IntTree

abstract class Result
case object Done extends Result
case class Next( n:Int, f : ( Unit => Result ) ) extends Result

def Sum(tree: IntTree): Int = {
  def walk( t : IntTree) : Unit = t match {
    case EmptyTree => ()
    case Node(v, left, right) => {
      walk(left)
      reset {
        shift { k: (Unit => Result) => Next(v, k) }
        walk(right)
      }
    }
  }
  def start( t : IntTree) = { walk(t); Done }
  def sumResult( ls : Result, acc : Int) : Int = ls match {
    case Done => acc
    case Next(value, k) => {
      sumResult(k(), acc + value)
    }
  }


  sumResult( start(tree), 0 )
}
```

I am also wondering if Delimited Continuations are the right tool for this job. I know this problem can be solved efficiently passing an explicit stack, but I would like to understand how to use cps in Scala.

Comment: Continued support for delimited continuations is iffy, given that they (as currently designed) introduce a lot of complexity without enabling very much that you can't do manually with a little extra syntax.  So I'm not sure understanding how to use CPS is a valuable skill to have (though it can still be a good general experience in how to think through certain kinds of things).  Also, you should search _Scala trampoline_ for this particular application!  (Not CPS at all.)

Comment: Thank you. So it is something halfway being discontinued and not the right tool for the job. It was more or less an experiment of using the cps approach that I already knew from other languages to solve this kind of problem. I would take a look at trampolines ( they will be supported in the future? as far as you know ). I am however interested in seeing a solution to this puzzle :)

Comment: Trampolines don't take any special machinery to work; they're just using basic Scala features to have an implicit heap-based stack (effectively).